# get_posts returns posts by current user only

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a wordpress blog that has many users roles. When logged in as `admin` `get_posts` seems to return all the `posts` but when logged in as `retailer`( role I created ) I only get the posts that the logged in user created

```
$argArray = array('post_type' => $type, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'orderby' => 'title','numberposts' => -1 );
 $posts = get_posts($argArray);
```

This code when logged in as admin returns all the posts in the site but when logged in as retailer return only the posts that the user authored.

BTW `$type` is a `post_type`

There is no mention of this in the documents or anywhere. is it something I am doing wrong or is it the way this is supposed to be?

Thanks in advance!!

UPDATED

AS I am looking over this it seems that worpdress query does add author argument in the wordpress query.I did new WP_Query() and checked.

This is the part that I want to remove `wp_posts.post_author = 347` This is not present in the query made by admin. I have seen `remove_query_arg` in wordpree query but not sure when and how to use it and if it can be used to remove this argument in the query at all.

Help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to make sure, you assigned appropriate [`roles and capabilites`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) for your role `retailer`.

`get_posts` uses `WP_Query`, where those restrictions are verified.

Eventually, take look at [`get_pages`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages), as I checked it, in the query there in no such a verification, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Thanks or the answer.I have tried using perm parameter in get_posts but it did not work.. I have tried ignore_sticky_posts also did not work. I think I will have to make a direct query to the database..